# Make a Progress bar that update based on a subprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, pyqt6

I am trying to do a simple gui with python using the PyQt6 library, and i want to make a progress bar that update based on the output of another script, but my program can't stop running while the progress bar is on progress.

I tried using subprocess library to call the other script and multiprocessing for handle the output of it while the main program still running, but, as the multiprocessing process and the main file don't share memory, i tried to use a multiprocessing manager to create the progress bar and share it, but now i am getting a `BrokenPipeError: [WinError 109] the pipe has been ended`.
Here is the code:

```
import time
import sys
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QDialog,
    QDialogButtonBox,
    QFormLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QLabel,
    QProgressBar,
)

class ProgressBar(QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMaximum(100)
        self._active = False
        self.setTextVisible(False)

    def setBar(self, i):
        self.value = i

    def changeColor(self, color):
        css = """
            ::chunk {{
                background: {0};
            }}
        """.format(color)
        self.setStyleSheet(css)

class ShrDt(BaseManager):
    pass

ShrDt.register('ProgressBar', ProgressBar)

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.setWindowTitle("QDialog")

        dialogLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        formLayout = QFormLayout()
        confBtn = QPushButton('Configurações')
        self.ligarBtn = QPushButton('Iniciar o aplicativo')
        statusLbl = QLabel('Desligado')
        self.ligado = False
        formLayout.addRow(confBtn)
        formLayout.addRow(self.ligarBtn)
        formLayout.addRow("Status: ", statusLbl)
        dialogLayout.addLayout(formLayout)
        connBar = dataSharer.ProgressBar()
        connBar.setBar(4)
        connBar.changeColor('gray')
        buttons = QDialogButtonBox()
        buttons.addButton('Fechar', QDialogButtonBox.ButtonRole.ActionRole)
        dialogLayout.addWidget(connBar)
        dialogLayout.addWidget(buttons)
        self.ligarBtn.clicked.connect(self.iniciaPgKt)
        self.setLayout(dialogLayout)
        self.show()
        y, x = self.geometry().height(), self.geometry().width()
        self.setFixedSize(x, y)
    
    def iniciaPgKt(self):
        if self.ligado:
            self.ligarBtn.setText('Ligar o aplicativo')
            self.pgktPrc.close()
            self.pgkt.terminate()
            self.ligado = False
        else:
            self.ligarBtn.setText('Desligar o aplicativo')
            self.pgkt = subprocess.Popen(['call', r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\escola\tarefas\projeto integrador\alexa ajuda eu\Programas\Alexaajudaeu.bat'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            self.pgktPrc = Process(target=self.pgktHandler)
            self.pgktPrc.start()
            self.ligado = True

    def pgktHandler(self):
        antRes = ''
        while True:
            res = self.pgkt.communicate()
            if res != antRes:
                antRes = res
                print(res)
            time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ShrDt() as dataSharer:
        app = QApplication([])
        window = Window()
        app.exec()
    sys.exit(0)
```

For now, I'm not trying to interpret the information of the second script, just print it.

Useful information:

- i am using python 3.11;
- windows 11;

Comment: You cannot create widgets in other processes (nor even in other threads). I'd suggest you to use [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html) instead of multiprocessing.

Comment: @musicamante i wasn't able to do it using QProcess, but it made me find the QThread class, and it probably will work, thanks

Comment: QThread doesn't allow to directly run external programs. QProcess is what you should use, don't try to find unorthodox alternatives, try to find why your attempt didn't work. Note: if you need to run batch scripts, you have to use `cmd.exe`. Do some research on QProcess and batch scripting.